# Does new Chromium-based Edge have shorter vertical height than Chrome? Header half disappears in Edge, but is fine with Chrome?

Tags: html, css, web, frontend, web-frontend

I'm relatively new to Front End development, and have been trying to improve my core CSS skills.
I've come across a quirk between Edge (Chromium) and Chrome which does not make much sense to me.

I've attached two images of the same example index.html page opened in both Edge and Chrome.

You can see that in Chrome the text fits fine, but in Edge the text is cut in half! Does Edge do something different with the top margins?

[image]
[image]

Here is my attached HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>Hello, World!</header>
</body>
</html>
```

And the css:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100vw;
}

header {
    background-color: rgb(115, 165, 216);
}

header {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 60px;
}
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Maybe you scrolled down a bit so it seemed like it is clipped?

Comment: `height: calc(100vh - 40px)`and `height:60px` there's 20px playing around also. grid works fine with webkit..

Comment: @G-Cyrillus i've removed the <nav> tag and associated css for simplicity, but you can see problem still exists. Any further suggestions would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: @yazantahhan unfortunately not! definitely scrolled to top of window.